# Не считываются координаты касания с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не считываются координаты касания с помощью кода

```
$(window).on('touchstart', function(e){
                var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
                var starty = touchobj.pageY;
                alert(starty);
            });
```

При касании к экрану выводится окно с ответом undefined.
Подскажите, что неправильно. 
При замене

```
var starty = e.clientY;
```

или

```
var starty = touchobj.clientY;
```

код тоже не работает

Comment: Напишите `console.log(e)` и гляньте)

Comment: Консоль недоступна в мобильнике. как в алерт вывести?

Comment: На каком устройстве тестируете ?

Comment: Xiaomi redmi note 5

Comment: Попробуйте подключить телефон к компьютеру в режиме `ADB` и открить `chrome://devices/`. А там уже можно будет нормально отловить.

Comment: Откройте в браузере, потом нажмите `Ctrl-Shift-M`